# What does SetThreadLocale actually do?

Tags: windows, localization, internationalization, language-agnostic

I've spent the last week trying to demistify the behavior of embedded resources (via `.rc` files) in conjunction with internationalization, and it sure feels like some bizarre kind of computer archaeology.

Most information on this function is outdated or unhelpful, including the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreadlocale).

[Michael Kaplan](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/08/22/454360.html) does not think highly of it either, the information provided in that blog post seems no longer correct (i.e. I have not been able to reproduce any scenario in which `SetThreadLocale` has an observable effect).

On a reasonably modern system (say, Win7 and newer), what does `SetThreadLocale` *actually* do, i.e. which APIs are affected by "The Thread Locale" (whatever that is supposed to be)?

I've ruled out any resource loading `FindResource[Ex]`, including `LoadString`, dialog and menu functions; `FormatMessage`; the `strsafe.h` `*Printf` family; `datetimeapi.h`'s `GetDateFormat` et al; and standard message boxes.

Comment: Interesting question. (But you used the wrong link for Michael Kaplan)

Comment: @Danny_ds Whoops, good catch. Although admittedly it doesn't change much because the info isn't entirely up-to-date either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recent investigation shows that, SetThreadLocale() and GetThreadLocale() has almost been obsolete. At least from Win7+, `DialogBox`, `FindResource` etc's resource `LANGUAGE` matching behavior is not affected by `SetThreadLocale()` but affected by `GetThreadUILanguage()`.

I have a dedicated test program to show this conclusion: https://github.com/chjfth/trivials/tree/master/mswin/About2-muires

The MSDN page for `SetThreadLocale` lacks maintenance for many years. Some Microsoft staff updated it by patching, not by reworking. That page says,

> SetThreadLocale affects the selection of resources with a LANGUAGE statement.

I'm now almost certain it is **only true for Windows NT4, or for Windows 95/98**, quite out-dated Windows versions that no one is sticking to in year 2022. So everyone should agree to delete that paragraph to avoid misleading.

The only effect of SetThreadLocale I found is when we call some WinAPI related to `CP_THREAD_ACP`, for example, `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_THREAD_ACP, ...)`, the thread-locale value set by `SetThreadLocale()` will determine the codepage used by `MultiByteToWideChar`.

Comment: Interesting. I think I stumbled upon this some time ago too but didn't really think about the connection. After some googling I suppose this is a good enough answer... My initial concern was whether I, as a developer, am potentially causing future problems by setting *or not setting* the thread locale, but I am now fairly confident that it is irrelevant unless you are very explicit in your code about using it (either via `GetThreadLocale`, or, as you are pointing out in this answer, via `CP_THREAD_ACP`).